# Parse Json format excel file into table

Tags: python, json

I have an excel file with rows containing JSON formatted data. How do I convert it into a table format?

example:

```
row1[{"name":"val","age":"100"}]
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----+
|   name  | val |
+---------+-----+
|   age   | 100 |
+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

If you have a file with rows/records in JSON format, then you can use `pandas.read_json` with `orient`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('filename.json', orient='records')
```

`df` would be your data frame, with data in tabular format.

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html